# How to adjust the height of NSSegmentControl?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, height, nssegmentedcontrol

The height of NSSegmentControl can't be adjusted.

Is there anyone who knows how to do it?

Please let me know. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An NSSegmentedControl object implements a horizontal button made of multiple segments. 
And also it does not provide any APi to set the height. But you can set the width using - (CGFloat)widthForSegment:(NSInteger)segment.
 The only thing you can do is to set different styles using below api..
 - (void)setSegmentStyle:(NSSegmentStyle)segmentStyle